# call connectionstring in sqldatasource

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

How  can we call connection string in Sqldatasource from class instead of writing directly ?

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource  ID="sqldatasource" runat="server" ConnectionString="..." SelectCommand="sp"    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">    

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On code behind write

```
  SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString=Class1.StringConnectionObj;
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1121212/How-do-I-call-connection-string-in-sqldatasource-f

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CXXX { 
     public String ConnectionString() { 
           return "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Pooling=false;"; 
        } 
}
```

Declare an object

```
protected CXXX _myObject;
```

Then, in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         _myObject = new CXXX();
}
```

Then, in default.aspx, you can do:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource  ID="sqldatasource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%= CXXX .ConnectionString() %>" SelectCommand="sp"    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I tried like this eg:ConnectionString="<%= gm.ConnectionString() %>" but showing error  Keyword not supported: '<%'.

Comment: can you show your connection string?(password:optional)

Comment: public class CXXX
{
    



    public String ConnectionString()
    { 
        return "data source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Pooling=false;";
    }
    

}

Comment: Updated.. Add `.\\` before SQLExpress.